# Cannot see commit created by git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p head

Tags: git

I am experimenting with git for learning purposes.
I create a git repo which has an empty file `list.txt`.
I then add a line to `list.txt`

```
banana
```

I do `git add .` and `git commit -m "banana"`.
I then add another line to `list.txt`

```
banana
orange
```

I do `git add .` and then if I try `git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p head` it freezes and if I add a commit message `git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p head -m "orange"` it doesn't freeze and returns the commit sha `5baee21d46db4d47ca3b28fbf617ed9db08d8166` of the created commit. This commit seems to have the correct parent since `git rev-parse 5baee~` gives `079cd`. However when I run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` I obtain

```
079cdae (HEAD -> master) banana
```

Why can't I see the "orange" commit and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do git add . and then if I try `git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p head` it freezes

It doesn't "freeze"; it's waiting for you to enter a commit message on standard input. Also, that command will fail with:

```
fatal: not a valid object name head
```

You need to spell it `HEAD`. In any case, you can pass in a message using the `-m` option, or you can provide it on standard input, as in:

```
echo "Here is a message" | git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p HEAD
```

This creates a new commit, but that won't show up in e.g. `git log` because nothing references that commit. It's just floating around in your repository, not attached to anything. You probably want to update the current branch to move `HEAD` to the new commit. Assuming we're on the `main` branch:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/main <commit id>
```

Or in one single command:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/main $(git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p HEAD -m orange)
$ git log
commit f6b8947acf02a90fc11b8913071c6ecfcfe887dd (HEAD -> main)
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <...>
Date:   Fri Jan 19 10:35:33 2024 -0500

    orange

commit d190fd18cde97dc87bd37e142d3e1c21a9029ea3
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <...>
Date:   Fri Jan 19 10:34:43 2024 -0500

    banana
```

---

> Is this because I use windows?

Yes, the Windows filesystem is case-insensitive, so when you write `head` it will still find `.git/HEAD`.

> When I write `git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p HEAD` and the screen waits for my input, I tried inputting echo "Here is a message" and hitting enter, but it didn't work. How should I enter it?

`Enter` won't finish the message (if that were the case, how would you enter multiple lines?). If you are typing on standard input interactively, you would need to type the end-of-file character. Under Linux, this means `CTRL-D`. Under Windows, I *think* this is `CTRL-Z`? It's been a long time.

Comment: thanks so much larsks. The issue was indeed that I created a commit to which nothing point to. I realised I can also update the reference to head with `git reset --hard 5baee`. Two points that I would be glad if you could still clarify : I didn't need to spell `head` in uppercase in order to work. Is this because I use windows? Second : When I write `git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -p head` and the screen waits for my input, I tried inputting `echo "Here is a message"` and hitting enter, but it didn't work. How should I enter it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your additional questions.

Comment: Thank you. Looking around it seems that ctrl+Z is indeed the end-of-file but sadly it is not working for my git bash on windows

Comment: Maybe you need `CTRL-D` under git bash?

Comment: tried as well :(